# Executing sensors command (lm-sensor) in Lua

Tags: bash, ubuntu, lua, conky

I originally have this Lua script

```
function temp_watch()

    warn_value=60
    crit_value=80

    temperature=tonumber(conky_parse("${hwmon 1 temp 1}"))
    
    if cpu_tmp<warn_value then
        settings_table[1]['fg_colour']=normal
    elseif cpu_tmp<crit_value then
        settings_table[1]['fg_colour']=warn
    else
        settings_table[1]['fg_colour']=crit
    end
end
```

but for some reason,  hwmon 1 temp 1 is just stuck reporting 25C.  For this reason I switched to *sensors*.  In conky I am executing it using this:

```
${exec sensors | grep 'Package id 0' | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -c 2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

I tried using this solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666250/how-to-use-conky-variable-with-external-command.  Basically, replacing the *temperature=tonumber...*  to

```
temperature=tonumber(conky_parse("${eval $${exec sensors | grep 'Package id 0' | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -c 2,3,4,5,6,7}}"))
```

I also tried this: [is it possible to pipe output from commandline to lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177705/is-it-possible-to-pipe-output-from-commandline-to-lua).  Replaced *temperature=tonumber...*  to

```
local cpu_tmp = io.popen("exec sensors | grep 'Package id 0' | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -c 2,3,4,5,6,7")
temperature=tonumber(cpu_tmp)
```

Both outputted this error:
*llua_do_call: function conky_main execution failed: /home/joe/conky/conky-grapes/rings-v2_gen.lua:530: attempt to compare nil with number*

am I missing some variable conversion or is there any other syntax to execute bash in lua?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Can you provide the output of the command `sensors | grep 'Package id 0'`?

Comment: @Fravadona, here you go:
`Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)`

Comment: try this `temperature = tonumber(io.popen("sensors -u | awk '/temp1_input:/ {print $2; exit}'"):read('*a'))`

Comment: @Fravadona, That worked for a while but it complained that: `conky: llua_do_call: function conky_main execution failed: /home/joe/conky/conky-grapes/rings-v2_gen.lua:485: attempt to index a nil value
fopen(): Too many open files`

that line 485 is the one that you suggested.  I guess it needs to be closed once the before the function ends?

Answer (score 0):

lua.org gave me an answer. [The Complete I/O Model](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html).

```
local file= io.popen("sensors -u | awk '/temp1_input:/ {print $2; exit}'")
local temperature = tonumber(file:read('*a'))
     <SOME CODE HERE>
file:close()
end
```

It is not elegant but it seems to work.  I will be running the lua script for quite some time to ensure it wont have that  `too many open files` error

Many thanks to @Fravadona for pointing me in the right direction :-)